# Searching subarray and return master array key

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to search the array below. I need to search recursively for a needle in the subarray $something[key][#]. If one of the strings matches the needle, then I want to return the top-level key value telling me what page it's on. I've tried nesting foreach, but can't seem to get this one!

```
$something = Array
(
    [1corte.php] => Array
        (
            [0] => Posicionador de toras automático
            [1] => Equipamento para madeiras acima de 3 m de comprimento
            [2] => Bitolador automático
        )

    [geminada.php] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jimi cracks corn
            [1] => etc
            [2] => etc2
        )

    [etc.php] => Array
        (
            [0] => ...
```

Comment: Is the depth of the array fixed? You should also show what you have so far and how it is failing.

Comment: http://www.php.net/array_search#110120

Comment: Sorry, will do that in the future!

Answer (score 3):

Since I'm not seeing any actual evidence of recursion here, this should do just fine:

```
foreach ($something as $key => $values) {
    if (in_array($theValueYoureLookingFor, $values)) {
        echo 'Found it! The key is: ', $key;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Next time show what you have tried so far ...

```
function searchString($stringToSearch) {
    $results = array();
    foreach($something as $key => $value) {
        foreach($value as $data) {
            if($data == $stringToSearch)
                results[] = $key;
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: This is working fine for the first top-level key, but after that the function doesn't continue to pull any results.

I have the function as above, and I call it like this:

foreach($re1 as $re){
   echo '<div title="'.options_search($re, $optionsFinal).'">'.$re.'</div>';
  }

Comment: You've never written anything about that. So next time better describe what you are looking for. I've edited my answer. This will return all found keys. Call this at first and loop over the result-array.